# Is it possible to import a p5js file into another file?

Tags: javascript, file, p5.js

I was wondering if it is possible to important a p5js file into another file. I am creating a non linear adventure game. If the player presses on a certain button, I want that button to activate a mini game that I have in another p5js file.

```
function mouseReleased() {
  cursor(ARROW);

  if (scene0 == true) {
    if ((mouseY > 162) && (mouseY < 248) && (mouseX > 54) && (mouseX < 278)){
      scene0 = false;
      scene1= true;
    }
  }
    if (scene1 == true) {
    if ((mouseY > 408) && (mouseY < 482) && (mouseX > 52) && (mouseX < 222)){
      scene1 = false;
      miniGame1 = true;
    }
  }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is **yes** it's possible. In fact it's the default behavior.

Let's say you have this HTML content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="mini-game.js"></script>
        <script src="main-game.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <p>My HTML</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is `mini-game.js`:

```
function miniGame(){
  console.log('mini game');
}
```

And here is `main-game.js`:

```
function mainGame(){
  miniGame();
}
```

Notice that the code in `main-game.js` can run the `miniGame()` function defined by the `mini-game.js` file.

You might hit a snag if you are defining P5.js functions in both functions. If this is the case, you'll have to refactor your code to use [instance mode](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Global-and-instance-mode) or to take in the sketch as an argument.

Comment: I'm currently trying instance mode but I'm having a little bit of trouble. I am getting an error somewhere. I updated the code.

Comment: @metrocode Please post new questions in their own posts.

Comment: I apologize. I will do so.